# android usbhid touchscreen

Tags: android, usb

**Исходные данные:**
Есть две android tv приставки, обе на android 6 и сенсорный монитор Asus, тач которого работает через модуль ядра usbhid
Одинаковые архитектуры armv8l, одинаковые версии ядер 3.14.29, но разные сборки android
Так же отличаются процессорами: s912 (Vontar Z5 Supermax) и s905x (X96)

**Суть проблемы:**
На одной приставке тачскрин нормально заводится и работает из коробки, на другой - нет

**Первая приставка (на s905x):**

После подключения usb тачскрина ядро говорит следующее:

```
usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci-hcd
input: ILITEK ILITEK Multi-Touch as /devices/c9000000.dwc3/xhci-hcd.0.auto/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:222A:0045.0003/input/input5
hid-multitouch 0003:222A:0045.0003: input,hiddev0: USB HID v1.10 Device [ILITEK ILITEK Multi-Touch] on usb-xhci-hcd.0.auto-2/input0
```

Далее создаются девайсы в /dev и всё работает:

```
root@p212:/ # ls /dev/usb/                                                     
hiddev0
input1-1:1.0
usbmisc1-1:1.0
```

**Вторая приставка:**

После подключения usb тачскрина ядро говорит только следующее и больше ничего:

```
usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci-hcd
```

В /dev/usb, соответственно, пусто, тач не работает

В обоих случаях при подключении в /sys/bus/usb/devices/ появляется новое устройство и видно, что оно работает под драйвером usbhid
Так же на обеих приставках идентичные выводы lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 222a:0045
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать, где может быть проблема со второй приставкой.

Comment: Ну, на них наверняка разная реализация xhci, соответственно и драйверы, соответственно и код разный и т.д. Убедитесь как говорится, что "провод питания подключен", т.е. все исходные действительно до определённого момента совпадают. Ах, ещё проверьте VBUS.